# Java Calendar getTimeInMillis returning wrong time

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am working with the Java Calendar class for android however I am getting some unexpected behaviour.

When I test the following code it gives me the desired results:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis(); // returns 0 indicating that they are synced
```

However when I change the values of the Calendar instance, it seems that it no longer returns the correct value for getTimeMillis.

For example:

```
// Current time : 1:56pm

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 13);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

cal.getTimeInMillis();           // returns 1411448454463
System.currentTimeMillis();      // returns 1411407834463

cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();  // returns 40620000
```

As you can see `cal.getTimeInMillis()` returns a number larger than `System.currentTimeMillis()` even though the time should be earlier (1:00pm vs 1:56pm).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `Calendar.HOUR`?

Comment: Wow, what a silly mistake. I should be using Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(               // Capture the current moment…
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )  // … as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (time zone).
)                                // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.with(                           // Adjusting…
    LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 )       // …by replacing the time-of-day
)                                // Produces a fresh (second) `ZonedDateTime` object, with values based on the original. Known as Immutable Objects pattern.
.toString()
```

> 2018-04-24T13:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes originally bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

Get the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

To represent the new desired time-of-day, use `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ;  // 1 PM.
```

Adjust the existing `ZonedDateTime` to this time-of-day, producing a fresh `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtThirteen = zdt.with( lt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).